# как сымитировать задержку роутера

Tags: маршрутизация, angular5, angular

как можно при клике на `<nav routerLink="" class="pages__link">`
сымитировать задержку *роутера* и что бы я мог вводить на сколько секунд,
или даже сделать какой то *калбек* от клика до загрузки страницы что бы можно было поставить *прилодер* и прописать какие то стили

**app.component.html**

```
<header class="df jcc aic">
  <nav class="page df jcc aic">
      <nav routerLink="" class="pages__link">{{ 'home' | uppercase }}</nav>
      <nav routerLink="about" class="pages__link">{{ 'about' | uppercase }}</nav>
      <nav routerLink="galery" class="pages__link">{{ 'galery' | uppercase }}</nav>
  </nav>
</header>
 <div class="container" [@fadeAnimation]="o.isActivated ? o.activatedRoute : ''">
   <router-outlet #o="outlet"></router-outlet>
 </div>
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
export const routes: Routes = [
        { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
        { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
        { path: 'galery', component: GaleryComponent }
    ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов, один из вешать `click` `EventListener` и делать delay:

```
<nav (click)="go('/')" class="pages__link">{{ 'home' | uppercase }}</nav>
<nav (click)="go('/about')" class="pages__link">{{ 'about' | uppercase }}</nav>
<nav (click)="go('/gallery', 2000)" class="pages__link">{{ 'galery' | uppercase }}</nav>
```

В компоненте:

```
private defaultDelay = 1000;

constructor(private router: Router) {}

public go(url: string, delay?: number): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.router.navigateByUrl(url);
    }, delay ? delay : this.defaultDelay);
}
```

Второй вариант - использовать резолвер:

```
// delay.resolver.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve } from '@angular/router';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { delay } from 'rxjs/operators/delay';

@Injectable()
export class DelayResolver implements Resolve<null> {
    private delay = 1000;

    public resolve(): Observable<null> {
        return of(null).pipe(delay(this.delay));
    }
}
```

Так как это провайдер - регистрируем его в модуле для инжектора:

```
// app.module.ts
import { AppRouterModule } from './app.router.module';

import { DelayResolver } from './delay.resolver';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...,
        AppRouterModule
    ],
    declarations: [...],
    providers: [
        DelayResolver
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Точно также указываем резолвер в модуле роутинга:

```
// app.router.module.ts
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { DelayResolver } from './delay.resolver';

const routes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    resolve: [DelayResolver]
}, {
    path: 'about',
    component: AboutComponent,
    resolve: [DelayResolver]
}];

export const AppRouterModule: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

`Resolver` - это так называемый `data provider`, вкратце это синглтон, который делает "что-то" перед инициализацией компонента на определенном lifecycle хуке роутера, но в данном случае он просто делает задержку на 1000мс перед тем как инициализируется компонент.